# Inserting HTML with jQuery document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a beginner at jQuery and I'm trying to insert a Facebook like button through the jQuery document.ready function.

My external Javascript file (loaded after the jQuery script) has the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if ($('#fb_btn').length) {
  var fb_code = "";

  fb_code += "<iframe src=\"http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=" + escape(document.URL) +"&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;\" allowTransparency=\"true\" >";

  $('#fb_btn').prepend(fb_code);
}

});
```

My HTML code for where I want the button is

```
<span id="fb_btn"></span>
```

Currently, nothing seems to load into the `span`.

I'm trying to use this instead of inserting the code directly because inserting directly slows down the page down a bit too much.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if this would really cause a problem, but technically an `<iframe>` is a block-level element, and as such it can't "legally" be inside a `<span>`.

Comment: My guess is that you need to add a closing `</iframe>`. Update: And what @Pointy says - stuff like this tends to behave strangely, especially in FF. Try making `fb_btn` a `div`

Comment: External JS files don't need to be in, or contain, a `$(document).ready();` wrapper. I'm not sure if this is the problem, but it's likely a complicating factor.

Comment: @David yes they need document.ready, if they do DOM manipulating things. Only if they contain functions that are called from elsewhere is the document.ready not necessary

Comment: @Pekka, ah...I stand corrected (I really should move my jQuery outside of my document's head one of these days... **cough**), thanks =)

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I tried adding a closing iframe tag as well as change it to a `div`. It still doesn't seem to work. =( If it helps, here's a link to a page thats supposed to show the button: http://www.techairlines.com/2010/10/23/slow-facebook-like-button/. The `fb_btn` div is located in the orange box under the post. The script is called right before `</head>`. Thanks again.

Comment: Alternatively, if you, for whatever reason, simply *have* to use a `span` here, you might be able to get away with setting the span to `display:block`.

Comment: @treeface `span` isn't necessary. I just changed it to `div` and it doesn't seem to work either. Hmm is there something wrong with my script code such as defining what fb_code is?

Comment: @treeface Thanks for the response. Right now, I have jQuery loaded at the beginning in `head`. My facebook button script is placed in the footer after a few other jQuery scripts such as Superfish. The other scripts are working but this one isn't. 

I previously had it in the `head` section but that also didn't work. I tried the script on a blank page loading nothing but jQuery and then the `$(document).ready()`. This also didn't work, so there might be an issue with the script itself.

Comment: Maybe you need to show more code. I copy+pasted the script into a JSFiddle and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/rQM6p/

Answer (score 1):

Brian, the errors you're getting on your page seem to be related to the absence of the `$` variable. Are you sure you're running your `$(document).ready()` only *after* you load your jQuery scripts? Remember...Javascript runs from top to bottom, so if you load your jQuery script after you run anything on the `$` or `jQuery` variables, you will get object undefined errors.

Then, to reiterate what others have said, you should probably close that html string with `</iframe>` and put the iframe in a block-level element.

Answer (score 1):

I think I just fixed the problem by updating the jQuery on my site. It was version 1.4.2. By using Version 1.4.3, everything seems to work fine.

Either that or there was something modified incorrectly with the jQuery I had.

Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: Seems odd that that would be the source of the problem.

Comment: As a note to anyone that may be viewing this in the future, the problem was actually jQuery No Conflict mode. WordPress has jQuery run in No Conflict mode so my $ tags didn't work. Updating jQuery basically disabled the No Conflict edit, hence causing this to work.

I just had to wrap the code in this:
    $(document).ready(function(){